# OpenMP Multithreads becoming one thread

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I am programming using OpenMP to get to learn about multithreads. Is it possible for any thread, which is any thread of 11 in this case, to reach the return statement at the end while some threads may be still working on something in the for loop? Or do they become one master thread again after line 13?

```
int np, iam;
#pragma omp parallel private(np, iam) num_threads(11)
{
    np = omp_get_num_threads();  
    iam = omp_get_thread_num();  

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        std::cout << i;
        doStuff(i);
        }
    }
}     // line 13
// synchronize necessary?
return 0;
```

Comment: AFAIK after line 13 the threads have completed and you're back to a single thread of execution. The whole idea behind OpenMP is to be writing single thread code whilst dropping hints using pragmas as to what might be parallelisable, leaving OpenMP to work out what to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit barrier ar the end of the `parallel` construct, so no synchronization is necessary. Any further code is executed only by the master thread (the one that had `thread_num == 0` within the parallel region), and only after all threads have reached the end of the parallel region.